# Limiting the sum of a column by a value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in MS SQL that looks like this

```
    ID           DATE              LIMIT     VALUE
    1      2016-01-01 00:00:00      10        5
    1      2016-02-01 00:00:00      10        3
    1      2016-03-01 00:00:00      10        1
    1      2016-04-01 00:00:00      10        3
    2      2016-01-01 00:00:00      15        16
    2      2016-02-01 00:00:00      15        5
    3      2016-01-01 00:00:00       8        1
    3      2016-02-01 00:00:00       8        2     
    3      2016-03-01 00:00:00       8        2
    3      2016-04-01 00:00:00       8        0
    3      2016-05-01 00:00:00       8        1
```

I would like to create a SELECT statement that will capped the sum of VALUE by the LIMIT. As shown below

```
    ID           DATE              LIMIT     VALUE
    1      2016-01-01 00:00:00      10        5
    1      2016-02-01 00:00:00      10        3
    1      2016-03-01 00:00:00      10        1
    1      2016-04-01 00:00:00      10        1
    2      2016-01-01 00:00:00      15        15
    2      2016-02-01 00:00:00      15        0
    3      2016-01-01 00:00:00       8        1
    3      2016-02-01 00:00:00       8        2     
    3      2016-03-01 00:00:00       8        2
    3      2016-04-01 00:00:00       8        0
    3      2016-05-01 00:00:00       8        1
```

As you can see, the value in row 4,5, and 6 is changed so that the running total of value by ID, DATE,and LIMIT will not exceed LIMIT. (Row 6 that has 0 in VALUE can be deleted.)

To be clear, LIMIT applies to the running total, based on ordering by DATE (thanks Damien_the_unbeliever to make it clearer)

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: so when cap limit exceeds  you are trying to set that to default value of 1 ?

Comment: could there be negative numbers or zeroes in the value column?

Comment: So, to be clear, `LIMIT` applies to the *running total*, based on *ordering* by `DATE` (rather than `GROUP`ing, as your question says).

Comment: to TheGameiswar no, the cap limit should not be exceed at all, like in ID=2

Comment: to dean: can have zeroes but no negative number

to Damien_the_unbeliever: that's correct. let me update the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces the desired result set, and is hopefully reasonably easy to read and reason about<sup>1</sup>:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,[DATE] datetime not null, LIMIT int not null,
                  VALUE int not null)
insert into @t(ID,[DATE],LIMIT,VALUE) values
(1,'2016-01-01T00:00:00',10,5 ),
(1,'2016-02-01T00:00:00',10,3 ),
(1,'2016-03-01T00:00:00',10,1 ),
(1,'2016-04-01T00:00:00',10,3 ),
(2,'2016-01-01T00:00:00',15,16),
(2,'2016-02-01T00:00:00',15,5 ),
(3,'2016-01-01T00:00:00', 8,1 ),
(3,'2016-02-01T00:00:00', 8,2 ),
(3,'2016-03-01T00:00:00', 8,2 ),
(3,'2016-04-01T00:00:00', 8,0 ),
(3,'2016-05-01T00:00:00', 8,1 )

select ID,[DATE],LIMIT,
    CASE
        WHEN v2 > LIMIT THEN 0
        WHEN COALESCE(v2,0) + VALUE > LIMIT THEN LIMIT - COALESCE(v2,0)
        ELSE VALUE
    END as VALUE
from
    @t t
        cross apply
    (select SUM(VALUE) from @t v where v.ID = t.ID and v.[DATE] < t.[DATE]) v(v2)
```

Results:

```
ID          DATE                    LIMIT       VALUE
----------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
1           2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 10          5
1           2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 10          3
1           2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 10          1
1           2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 10          1
2           2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 15          15
2           2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 15          0
3           2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 8           1
3           2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 8           2
3           2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 8           2
3           2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 8           0
3           2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 8           1
```

We're just using a `CROSS APPLY` here to find out what the total value is for all previous rows (based on `DATE`) and using a short `CASE` expression to decide which of three situations each row could be in - we've either exceeded the limit already, we're the row that exceeds the limit<sup>2</sup>, or we're well below the limit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Also note how I've transformed your sample data into something that takes up as much/slightly less space than the sample in your question but also has the massive benefit that it's *runnable* code to generate the sample data

<sup>2</sup>The original version of this answer failed if the first row of a set exceeded the limit (as for the question's `ID` 2 rows). It has since been corrected to use `COALESCE` for this case.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is to do

```
LEAST( YourTable.Limit, SUM( YourTable.Value ) ) as Value
```

and a group by the ID and Date, but not enough of your raw data to show complete SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, rt=SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [DATE] )
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT  ID,DATE,LIMIT
       ,VAL = CASE WHEN rt - value > LIMIT THEN 0 
          ELSE CASE WHEN rt > LIMIT  THEN rt - LIMIT ELSE value END END
FROM cte
```